# audio file is not playing in html

Tags: html

I am unable play audio file in my html.Below code is sample

```html
<html>
<body>
<audio controls>
  <source src="http://localuat.virinchihospitals.com/vfImg/UploadAudio/1529667425971.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">

</audio>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your audio file right? When I try this code with an other audio file, it is working. When I go to your link in my browser, it is not working.

Comment: Does the link work when you enter url in your browser? Doesn't for me. It would seem the file is corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

Your audio file is not right/valid its not working, Open this in your tab and see

http://localuat.virinchihospitals.com/vfImg/UploadAudio/1529667425971.mp3

Comment: In VLC---->Media--->open network stream--->network url . Audio is playing

Answer (score 0):

I do not have privileges to comment, but it seems to me that your mp3 file does not exist, follow an example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<audio controls>
  <source src="http://www.orangefreesounds.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Horse-and-carriage-passing-by.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```